# Parallel Processing of SSAS partitions

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

We are currently using SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition. SSAS does not support the processing of multiple partitions concurrently. SQL Server Enterprise Edition does support this.

I have two questions:
1. What is the term for the ability of SSAS to process multiple partitions at once?
2. Does the SQL Server BI Edition support this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallel partition processing for Multidimensional models is available in SQL 2012 Analysis Services BI edition. I have a client on that version and editions and can confirm it does process in parallel.

Comment: @Gabe how I read that link you provide is that in SQL2012-SQL2014 there are zero SSAS feature differences between Enterprise edition and BI Edition. What do you see that makes you think it isn't supported?

Comment: you're completely right, I must have looked at a different table. I'll delete my comment.