# Does SQL Server 2017 Standard support parallel processing in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have just switched our multidimensional cube from SQL Server 2017 Enterprise to SQL Server 2017 Standard, and it looks like parallel processing is no longer working. There are no warnings or errors, but when I run an XMLA command to process a set of partitions inside a Parallel batch, the processing seems to just run in series.

The [official Microsoft edition comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-analysis-services-2017) makes no mention of any differences in support for parallel processing in multidimensional models. I have found several old posts that seem to indicate it was not supported in SQL Server 2012, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427054/parallel-processing-of-ssas-partitions) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/parallel-processing-not-supported-on-standard-edition-of-analysis-services), but this is still pretty circumstantial.

Can anyone confirm whether SQL Server Standard Analysis Services 2017 does, or is supposed to support parallel processing? Ideally with a link to some official documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to raise this question with Microsoft support, and their eventual response was "SSAS Standard version multidimensional model does not support parallel processing".

So it seems this is an undocumented limitation of SQL Server Standard edition.

Comment: Thanks a ton for clarifying something that kept us busy for what seemed like an endless amount of time...